# Bootstrap 4 : How to have a full width navbar with the container-fluid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap navbar inside a container-fluid, I need to make the navbar fill all the weight of the container-fluid, can any one help please. if I put the navbar outside the container-fluid my problem is resolved, but I need to do the same thing just in CSS because I don't have access to the HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

Use this css code.

```
.container-fluid {
    margin: 0!important;
    padding: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: yes it work but here we change the boostrap behavior and all other container-fluid, there is no way to change just navbar css ?

Comment: Can you share your codes that including the container-fluid?

Comment: Use CSS selector like "header .container-fluid {}". It will work only for that container-fluid.

Comment: ok i have made this code: https://jsfiddle.net/qxf9naph/25/

Comment: Congratulations! I think you can approve my answer. :)

Comment: your solution work but you well change all container-fluid and i need just to fit navbar to the container

Comment: your solution work but you well change all container-fluid and all the content of the container well fill the container and in my side i need just navbar

Answer (score -1):

easy with css:

```
.navbar {
   margin: 0 -2rem 0 -2rem;
   width: auto;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2dszau7y/18/